# How to disable validation controls in a user control when rendered into a page

Tags: vb.net, validation, user-controls

I am trying to delete a customer record. In the page I have an usercontrol for address and it has some validation. I cannot delete the record since it fires the validation controls. How can I disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)`="False"` on your `BtnDelete`.